# Нажатие кнопки меняет цвет текста в другом файле

Tags: java, android, button, текст

Есть два `Fragment` в обоих есть по кнопке. Допустим в `Fragment1.java` есть кнопка с текстом - "Кнопка 1". Во втором `Fragment2.java` тоже есть кнопка но с текстом - "Текст 2". Как сделать чтобы по нажатию на "Кнопка 1" цвет текста "Текст 2" менялся на красный. Я понимаю что они находятся в разных java файлах, но это можно как-то сделать? Если бы эти две кнопки находились в одном java файле, то я написал бы что-то типа:

```
knopka1.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> 
{
        text2.setTextColor(textColor2);

   return false;
});
```

Но из-за того что они находятся в разных фалах такая запись не работает.

Comment: я бы сделал через общую вьюмодель

Comment: @Cypher могли бы вы расписать как это сделать? Или скинуть источник с чем-то похожим?

Comment: https://medium.com/@misamuna/share-data-between-fragments-in-kotlin-bc7893ee6214